# Django 1.9 - IntegrityError on update

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    configuration_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    configuration_value = models.TextField()
    configuration_description = models.TextField("a brief description of this setting", blank=True)
```

The above is my model. I am able to able to add configurations using the admin. I have not configured any customizations on the admin. It is a very basic

```
admin.site.register(Configuration)
```

When I update an existing configuration with admin, it throws an IntegrityError

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "config_configuration_configuration_key_key"
DETAIL:  Key (configuration_key)=(SAMPLE_CONFIGURATION) already exists.
```

My question: Shouldn't the admin know that an existing configuration is modified and handle this accordingly? Am I missing something? To be clear - SAMPLE_CONFIGURATION - there is only one such row in the table with that `configuration_key`. I am trying to edit the `configuration_value` for that row using the admin and it throws the Integrityerror.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine, there must be no error. Update Django to the current version and try again.

Also try to isolate the problem. Use tests to reproduce the issue. If tests are passed, then problem not in your code.

Double check what is inside DB, try to update row directly using SQL.

This test updates configuration_value without any integrity issues.

```
class ConfigurationModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_uniq_issue(self):
        config = Configuration.objects.create(configuration_key='SAMPLE_CONFIGURATION',
                                              configuration_value='value')
        config.save()

        config.configuration_value = 'updated_value'
        config.save()
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot update Django without impacting updating other parts of the code. I will try running the tests.

Comment: I advise you to run generated SQL directly. Set DEBUG to True and check value  of >>> from django.db import connection  >>> connection.queries and then run this SQL command in mysql.